# Issue with Wordpress/Bootstrap navbar where there is a gap between the submenu and the navbar

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am currently migrating a site to Wordpress from a custom-created HTML/CSS/Bootstrap website. I have downloaded the Navwalker .php extension that automatically converts the Bootstrap navbar to Boostrap.

Here is the gap I am referring to. https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0HHc.jpg
Where specifically in my CSS can I fix this problem?

Here is the php section in my header.php file:

```
                <?php
                $args = array(
                    'menu' => 'header-menu',
                    'menu_class' => 'nav nav-pills nav-justified navbar-inverse',
                    'container' => 'false',
                    'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
                );
                wp_nav_menu ( $args );
                ?>
```

If anyone could direct me toward the right place, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Looks like there is a margin-top for the ul on the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your theme's style.css file:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Feel free to play with the value of `0` so that it lines up nicely with your navbar. For example, you could instead use `-10px` or `10px`.